# How to find the basis of an intersection of vector spaces, along with vector spaces relative to one another.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

### The Question

I would appreciate a  nudge in the right direction. I have two vector spaces $V_1$ and $V_2$, given spanning sets for both respectively. I am trying to find a basis for $V_1 \cap V_2$ and a basis for $V_1$ relative to $V_1\cap V_2$.

Consider a vector space $V=K^4$ and its subspaces

$$V_1 = span \left\{ \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    3 \\ 3 \\ 2 \\ 2
  \end{matrix}
  \right), \left(
   \begin{matrix}
    2 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 2
  \end{matrix}
  \right),\left(
   \begin{matrix}
    0 \\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 0
  \end{matrix}
  \right),\left(
   \begin{matrix}
    2 \\ 3 \\ 2 \\ 1
  \end{matrix}
  \right) \right\},V_2 = span \left\{ \left(
  \begin{matrix}
    2 \\ 3 \\ 1 \\ 1
  \end{matrix}
  \right), \left(
   \begin{matrix}
    2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 2
  \end{matrix}
  \right),\left(
   \begin{matrix}
    2 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 1
  \end{matrix}
  \right)\right\}$$
Find the bases of $V_1$ and $V_2, V_1 \cap V_2$ and $V_1$ relative to $V_1 \cap V_2$

### My Understanding

I calculated the basis of the intersection to be the column vectors $(0,-2,0,1)^T$ and $(2,2,0,1)^T$, I did this by constructing the matrix $(Base(V_1)|-Base(V_2))$ and finding a basis for the kernel, of the form =( ). I then proceeded to calculate the column vectors by taking $Base(V_1)\cdot$ for each basis vector of the kernel. However, I can not see how the column vectors $(0,-2,0,1)^T$,$(2,2,0,1)^T$ can form a basis of $V_1$ as they do not have a third entry.

Comment: Consider $V_1$ with basis $(0,0,1)$ and $V_2$ with basis vectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. The intersection will simply be $V_1$ which has two entries that are zero. It doesn't mean anything is wrong.

Comment: Are you saying that you were expecting the basis for $V_1\cap V_2$ to have three elements but there are only two? I find it quite reasonable that the intersection would have dimension 2 (assuming that $V_1$ has dimension 3).

Comment: I was expecting the basis for $V_1\capV_2$ to have 4 elements, however I have two vectors both with 4 elements that both do not have a 3rd entry. I have not previously encountered this in my studies so it seems unusual to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a switch of basis because the basis $\{(0,-2,0,1)^T,(2,2,0,1)^T\}$ of $V_1 \cap V_2$ doesn't have three vectors in it, like the basis $\{(3,3,2,2)^T,(2,1,2,2)^T,(0,1,2,0)^T\}$ of $V_1$ does. But you could always find a third linearly independent vector $\vec{v_3}$ in $V_1$ such that $\{(0,-2,0,1)^T,(2,2,0,1)^T,\vec{v_3}\}$ is a basis for $V_1$, then you could write every vector in $V_1$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors of $V_1 \cap V_2$ and $\vec{v_3}$.

[image]